# How to pull particular property in nested array of object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Can any one please help how to pull particular property in nested array of object.

```
article:Array
 0:Object
articleId:"WMCA675107"
content:Array
0:Object
title:"my new title"
content:"asasasa"
Randid:300979
illustrations:Array
0:Object
title:"sss"
imagePath:"1559647117293.JPG"
randid:14528
1:Object
title:"xyz"
imagePath:"54124841548.JPG"
randid:88985
```

I tried to remove only imagePath in illustrations array.
I tried like this

```
Collections.user.update(
        { "article.articleId": req.body.articleId} ,
        { $pull: { 'article.$[].content.$[].illustrations':  { "imagePath":undefined  } } } ,
        function(err,result) {
          if(err)
           console.log(err);
           else
           console.log(result);
             res.send("Deleted");
      })
```

It removes the the entire illustrations of object. I need to remove only one property i.e., imagePath in illustrations array.

Please help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

`$pull` is going to remove the entire object if it finds a matching property within that object.  If you want to just remove that particular field, you'll have to set it to `undefined`.  Something like:

`illustrations.imagePath = undefined`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried what you says, and i updated in above, what i have tried. But the issue is undefined will affect to every object of imagePath in illustrations array. I want to update particular object in illustrations array.